# Why do we say "last night" and not "yesterday night"?

Tags: idioms, time

As from object, is there a rational reason for saying "last night" rather than  "yesterday night", though you would say "yesterday morning" and "yesterday afternoon"?

Comment: Er. Am I the only person who says "yesterday night"? I wasn't even aware that it's uncommon

Comment: Pure comic effect really. That phrase and 'today evening' always bring a chuckle when new speakers use them in conversation.

Comment: Well, I've been scolded by native English speakers more than once for saying that :) It just comes natural to me, as in both Italian and French you would say it (ieri sera and hier soir).

Comment: Similarly strangely, we do say 'next morning' but not 'next afternoon' or 'next night' (or rather, we do, but in 'the next afternoon' and not 'I'll see you next afternoon').

Comment: @nico: Yes, but consider "cette nuit" (ambiguous without context).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Edited:] You couldn't say *last morning* in most cases, because you might be referring to this morning if the hour of speaking is late (today's morning is the "last" morning then): it would be confusing if *last morning* could be either today or yesterday. The same applies to the afternoon. But you can't go later than "night": the last night that has passed (you would not use "last" for a period that is not over yet) is necessarily that of the day before today. This could be the reason why we use "last" only with "night". But there might be some entirely different historical reason instead; it is impossible to say without textual research.

We could theoretically use *yesterday night* as an alternative to *last night*; but it would be longer, which might be why it is never used. Or it could be some other reason.

Comment: Are you sure the length is the reason? My guess is that the reason for using "last night" over "yesterday night" has something to do with the "day" in "yesterday" ("day" often being the opposite of "night"), but this is only a guess.

Comment: And then there is the archaic "yesternight" ...

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with the logic that we don't use *yesterday night* because it is longer. We don't use "yesterday night" because we don't use it. The fixed phrase "last night" just has the effect of syntactic blocking; that is, the existence of the phrase "last night" prevents other seemingly logical ways of saying the same thing from being grammatical.

Comment: I guess it makes sense. Never thought of it this way. Thanks.

Comment: I agree completely with "we don't use ... because we don't use it."  English doesn't always make logical sense.  Sometimes things are the way they are because they "sound right."  In some ways this makes no less sense than other languages assigning feminine or masculine attributes to inanimate objects.

Comment: Fair enough. My whole post was merely a suggestion why it might be as it is, speculation; how could anyone prove that "last morning" isn't used for the reasons I gave? It could be that some writer in the 18th century started a random trend. It merely sounds somewhat logical, that is all: only historical text research could shed some light on this. I will change my post to reflect a more tentative view then.

Comment: Other languages *do* happily say "yesterday night" and things along these lines (German "gestern abend"), so any logic for why it just plain can't be "yesterday night" goes out the window.  It is probably just because we only have one word for that concept and "last night" was the one that ended up the winner.

Comment: @Kosmonaut: Good point. In Dutch we use the same (gisteravond, gisterochtend, gisternacht). However, the fact that a cause is not a sufficient or necessary cause doesn't mean that it can't be any cause at all: there are probably several complex factors at work, pushing and pulling in several directions, and chance. Should I just erase my entire answer? Perhaps an inventory of the many possible causes would be interesting.

Comment: @Kosmonaut: Please note, that "gestern Abend" means "yesterday evening", while "gestern Nacht" means "the other night". "Last night" in German is "letzte Nacht".

Comment: @mizo: Yes, but *abend* is used in places where English speakers use *night* (e.g. "What did you do last night?" - "I saw a movie" — this would be *gestern abend* in German).

Comment: @Kosmonaut: w.r.t my reply, the point was that "evening" and "Abend" don't span across day boundary, unlike "night" and "Nacht". I like to think that the logic behind using "last night" instead of "yesterday night" is to avoid the ambiguity caused by night taking place both in the beginning and the end of a day.

Comment: @mizo: Well, if you just don't like the German as an example, then let's go with Spanish: "ayer por la noche" means last night, and literally "yesterday at night".  It is different from yesterday evening (*anoche*).

Comment: @Kosmonaut: or French and Italian that say "hier soir" and "ieri sera" (=yesterday night)

Comment: @nico: But French says "cette nuit" (literally *this night*) for last night.

Comment: *Last night* is very convenient, IMO. And consider how you describe the night before that -- in English it's the *night before last*.

Answer (score 12):

Night is the time that spans over the change of days. I can refer to events that happened after midnight - indeed last night, but not yesterday. Thus, "yesterday night" would lead to ambiguity.

Comment: +1 Each day has only one morning period, one afternoon period, and one evening period, but it has two separate night periods.  The first night period spans the time between midnight and morning, and the second spans the time between evening and midnight.  As @mizo said, this leads to ambiguity when you use the term 'yesterday night'.

Answer (score 9):

Here's one possible explanation.

Many years ago (before Shakespeare), people didn't either say *yesterday night* or *last night* because they said *yesternight* instead. Shakespeare uses both *last night* and *yesternight*. When *yesternight* was still in use, *yesterday night* would have sounded strange, even though *last night* wouldn't. And when *yesternight* went out of use completely, *last night* was already too firmly established for *yesterday night* to be used.

Comment: Interesting idea.  :)

Answer (score 5):

"Yesterday night" is standard usage in British English. It means "the evening of yesterday".

Example from BBC News:

> BONFIRE NIGHT DEMO 0820: Eleven people have been arrested after scuffles broke out after protests by the Anonymous movement at Buckingham Palace and Parliament yesterday night.

http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-england-london-24831851

From The Guardian:

> City officials had been told the storm could make landfall yesterday night and in preparation the Texas National Guard called 600 troops to active duty yesterday morning.

http://www.theguardian.com/world/1999/aug/23/2

Comment: I so much like this answer.

Answer (score 1):

“Yesterday night” is less common than “last night”, but it does occur. The Oxford English dictionary has a quotation from 1654–5:  in C. H. Firth Clarke Papers (1899) III. 26, “Yesterday night came letters from Collonell (sic) Hacker”.

Answer (score 0):

Morning, afternoon and evening are the different phases or 'time frames' of the **day**, so *yesterday morning*, *yesterday afternoon* and *yesterday evening* are quite but natural. However, when *night* arrives, the *day* is gone or when the *day* is gone, we call it **night**.

Hence, YESTERDAY NIGHT is not logical.

This is my reason, but I may be wrong. :)

Comment: Please complete the following phrase "*yesterday evening are quite (?) but natural.*"