# Usage of "last evening"

Tags: word-usage, british-english

I have heard my friend say *yesterday evening* or *yesterday night*. I tell her it's *last evening* or *last night*. While she may be correct in that it is the *night of yesterday*, why is it then called *last night* (or *last evening*)?

Comment: It is the *last* night that has occurred. If it were still ongoing, it would be *tonight* or *this* evening.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do we say "last night" and not "yesterday night"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15718/why-do-we-say-last-night-and-not-yesterday-night)

Comment: @Colin Fine: I'm not so sure (though to be honest I've no doubt I'd have closevoted along with you if I hadn't already answered here! :). The thing is, I see this question as more about *yesterday/last **evening***, which isn't even mentioned in those earlier answers. Specifically, I now discover that there seems to be a US/UK split in respect of *evening* (being the "cusp" point between *morning/afternoon* and *night*, where almost all of us agree on *yesterday* for the former, and *last* for the latter).

Comment: "Yesterday evening" is reasonably idiomatic.  "Yesterday night" is not.

Answer (score 3):

If you're speaking on Tuesday about something that happened on Monday, it's ***yesterday***.

If you want to be more specific, you can say *yesterday **morning***, *yesterday **afternoon***, *yesterday **evening***. The exception here is that native speakers almost never say *?yesterday **night*** - it's invariably ***last*** night (and conversely, we don't say *?**last** morning/afternoon/evening*).

(Edit) Thanks to Talia for pointing out that US speakers actually prefer *last evening* over *yesterday evening*. As a Brit I find that odd, but at least we all agree *last* doesn't work for *morning/evening*.

If you're talking some time later (say, Friday) about what you did Tuesday, and you want to refer back to earlier events on Monday you can't use either *yesterday* or *last*, because they always mean *the day before the day **on** which you are speaking* (not *...the day **of** which you are speaking*). You have to use alternatives such as...

> *"On Tuesday I slept through my alarm because I'd stayed up late the **previous/preceding** evening"*.
>    (or *"...the evening/night **before**"*).

Comment: Fingers  I don't think I have ever heard any native English speaker say 'yesterday night'. Isn't it always 'last night'? Equally I HAVE heard people say 'last evening', but that was a long time ago. I think it has possibly passed out of use.

Comment: @WS2: At the time of writing, I knew that I personally wouldn't normally use [*yesterday **night***](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22yesterday+night%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). So I just made a quick check on Google Books (repeated in the link here in this comment), and figured that "About 21,200 results" implied other people *did* use it. But I now see that *yesterday night I went* generates only 500 hits, compared to over 270,000 for *last night I went*, so I'll have the courage of my [original] convictions and edit to reflect that.

Comment: I have an issue with your _?last evening_. Although journalists will normally use _yesterday evening_, in more immediate contexts _last evening_ doesn't seem to have less currency. Google gives about 230 hits ("the most relevant" ones; otherwise it gives millions) for _I/you/he/she/we/they said last night_ and 190 for its _yesterday evening_ variant. And personally, too, _last evening_ doesn't really hit my ear wrong, though I'm not sure if I actually use it, at least in the concerned sense (I do say, "On our last evening..." but that has a whole different context).

Comment: Personally I would not use 'last evening'. But that may be because I am not really an 'evening person'. I tend to use 'night' where others will use 'evening'. And I strongly suspect that is a relic of the Broad Norfolk with which I grew up. But associated with this question of 'last evening' is the wider issue about who says 'evening' and who says 'night' and in what circumstances. Does it depend on the time. Is there a moment when evening becomes night e.g. after 10.00pm for example?

Comment: @Talia: My answer only addresses *yesterday/last* insofar as they specifically refer to the day before time of speaking. To minimise "false positives", we can search Google Books for [but last night I](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22but+last+night+I%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), which generates a claimed 156,000 hits. When compared to just 64 instances of [but **yesterday** night I](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22but+yesterday+night+I%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), I think the conclusion is unmistakable. To all intents and purposes, we simply don't use that form.

Comment: That holds for the _night_; I was specifically focusing on the _evening_. Oh, no, I see where I've made a copy/paste error. I'm gonna have to delte the comment and post it again. Nah, I'll just post it again, with the typo corrected.

Comment: I have an issue with your _?last evening_. Although journalists will normally use _yesterday evening_, in more immediate contexts _last evening_ doesn't seem to have less currency. Google gives about 230 hits ("the most relevant" ones; otherwise it gives millions) for _I/you/he/she/we/they said last evening_ and 190 for its _yesterday_ variant. And personally, too, _last evening_ doesn't really hit my ear wrong, though I'm not sure if I actually use it, at least in the concerned sense (I do say, "On our last evening..." but that has a whole different context).

Comment: @Talia: [Further investigation](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=and+last+evening%2Cand+yesterday+evening&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cand%20last%20evening%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cand%20yesterday%20evening%3B%2Cc0) suggests something of a US/US split here. If you toggle between US/UK corpus, it seems *last evening* is more likely in the US. And I wouldn't mind betting the UK figures are skewed by some misclassified US instances - in practice, I think *last* is more a *distant* than a *close second* in the UK.

Comment: Hm, that's interesting. Those figures do reflect my Google search results: in the US _last evening_, overall, has a slight precedence over _yesterday evening_, but in the UK it's the other way around. Atlantic split reveals its face again...

Comment: @Talia: Well, I'm glad you brought it up. I've learnt something too, and I'll amend the answer accordingly. At least [a double check on *yesterday/last **morning***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=and+last+morning%2Cand+yesterday+morning&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cand%20last%20morning%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cand%20yesterday%20morning%3B%2Cc0) (and the same for *afternoon*) confirms my intuition that even Americans don't much favour *last* with those.

Comment: As an AmE speaker, 'last evening' sounds -very- odd to me. 'Last night' but 'yesterday evening' (in AmE, 'evening' is somewhat rare anyway.)

Comment: @Mitch: I'd be very surprised if *evening* were any more "rare" (relatively speaking) in the US than the UK. It's hardly enough to be significant, but [checking US/UK corpuses in NGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=evening&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cevening%3B%2Cc0), the usage figures in 2008 seem to be 0.0061% for the UK, and 0.0077% for the US. But then again I don't understand why both corpuses show an apparent increase since 2000. I'd have thought we all tend to just use *night* more these days.

Comment: I wasn't trying to say anything about BrE. But To the rest, nGrams is always questionable (one is never sure if what's being counted is the same as what we're thinking of). That is, nGrams is definitely objective but just not necessarily accurate. And I sorta trust my own bias.Sometimes introspection works.