# Why do we say 'last Monday morning' but not 'last morning'?

Tags: expressions, time, expression-choice

There was a very similar question asked about 'last night' and 'yesterday night' [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15718/why-do-we-say-last-night-and-not-yesterday-night) but I didn't really think the question was answered that definitively. Also, I thought about how we use other expressions that include last + date/time a bit more.

Is this because last Monday morning is unambiguous, and yesterday morning is also unambiguous whereas last morning is? Why doesn't last morning just mean the morning that passed if it is night time (and you are referring to a time in the same day), and if it is morning then it refers to yesterday's morning? I think this is still a probably with last Monday morning if you are using this expression on a Monday just after morning.

Comment: Often people will ask 'why does such a thing not exist'. The only honest answer is 'I don't know'. And I'm not sure who to complain to.

Comment: This is only an opinion. However, it seems to me having thought about it fairly often, that *yesterday* and *tomorrow* are compounds of prepositions and nouns. Like *this* and *that* and *next* and *last*, *yester* and *to* carry out the work usually done by prepositions. We therefore don't usually use prepositions of time with any of these expressions. I believe we don't say *next, last, this, that* when *yesterday* or *tomorrow* are up to the job. This excludes *last morning*, *next night* and so forth. It is *last night* which is the exception. Maybe because it straddles yesterday and today

Comment: @Araucaria and *last evening?*

Comment: It's difficult to see any real answer to this other than "it's common usage", here and now.  (Maybe in 500 yrs people will say "last morning.")

Answer (score -1):

> *Why doesn't last morning just mean the morning that passed if it is night time (and you are referring to a time in the same day), and if
>   it is morning then it refers to yesterday's morning?*

If it did, then it would be an ambiguous definition, because now you need to know what time of day or night the sentence was uttered in order to know what the speaker meant.  We don't often have such information at hand.  The current usage at least has a single meaning - "this morning" is the morning of the current day, and "Monday Morning" is the morning on Monday.

Comment: -1 because we manage to say *last evening* at all times of day and night and seem to know when we are talking about. In addition, ambiguity certainly does not stop us using many other, different phrases in English.